# Pytesseract keeps on getting syntax or path error

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-imaging-library, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to run a python code on my Raspberry Pi, in which I get from some [tutorial](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/optical-character-recognition-ocr-using-tesseract-on-raspberry-pi). I followed everything there; installed the necessary packages or library in order for me to run the script.

The first one:

```
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr
```

And I get these following messages.

```
   Reading package lists... Done
   
   Building dependency tree
   
   Reading state information... Done tesseract-ocr is already the newest
   version (4.0.0-2).
   
   The following package was automatically installed and is no longer
   required:   python-colorzero
   
   Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
   
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Proof here:[Screen shot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c90e4.png)

The second one is this:

```
pip3 install pytesseract
```

I changed pip to pip3, since I read somewhere that *pip* is already obsolete. And so, I get these messages:

```
   Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple,
   https://www.piwheels.org/simple
   
   Requirement already satisfied: pytesseract in
   /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (0.3.8)
   
   Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in
   /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from pytesseract) (5.4.1)
```

Proof here:[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKnoQ.png)

And lastly, in order for me to run the script. I install this.

```
pip3 install pillow
```

Same as the above one, I also used *pip3* in installing pillow. So, I get these messages:

```
   Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple,
   https://www.piwheels.org/simple
   
   Requirement already satisfied: pillow in
   /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (5.4.1)
```

Proof here:[Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFCz5.png)

After installing all the necessary requirements, I tried to run this simple script from the tutorial.

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('platen5.jpeg',cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) #Open the image from which charectors has to be recognized
#img = cv2.resize(img, (620,480) ) #resize the image if required

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #convert to grey to reduce detials
gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 11, 17, 17) #Blur to reduce noise

original = pytesseract.image_to_string(gray, config='')
#test = (pytesseract.image_to_data(gray, lang=None, config='', nice=0) ) #get confidence level if required
#print(pytesseract.image_to_boxes(gray))

print (original)
```

Unfortunately, I still get this syntax error thing though. The only thing I changed from the original script is the 'platen5.jpeg', since it is the saved image of a plate number I have on my file.

Here's the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "tut.py", line 1, in
>
> ```
> import pytesseract
> ```
>
> File "/home/pi/pytesseract/**init**.py", line 2, in
>
> ```
> from .pytesseract import ALTONotSupported
> ```
>
> File "/home/pi/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 88
>
> ```
> f"{tesseract_cmd} is not installed or it's not in your PATH."
> ```
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Proof here: [Screenshot 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVnnN.png)

I am sorry, I'm kinda new to python, and raspberry pi, so I am very dependent on the tutorials on the internet, so I have no idea in which part I did wrong. Or am I missing something? Or everything from the tutorial are already obsolete so, it doesn't work?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like this error message is coming from an   old version of Python. The `f`-string the message complains about was introduced in Python 3.7. So it appears that the interpreter that is running `tut.py` is not the one you think, and not the one where `tesseract` is installed. It is easy to have multiple versions of Python installed without realising it.

Comment: I do get the idea, but I am a bit confused. Is there a way for me to fix this thing up? By the way, thanks for answering. I'm trying to resolve this error since yesterday, but it seems I am just getting nowhere.

Comment: First thing is to find out the locations where Python is installed. The way to do that is platform dependent. Then be sure when you run `tut.py` to invoke the Python 3.7 installation where you did the installs, which appears to be `usr/local/lib/python3.7`, and not rely on some system default.